# A Spark long running program as web server

Tags: apache-spark

I have written multiple spark driver programs that load some data from HDFS to data frames and accomplish spark sql queries on it and persist the results in HDFS again. Now I need to provide a long running java program in order to receive requests and their some parameters(such as the number of top rows should be returned) from a web application (e.g. a dashboard) via post and get and send back the results to web application. My web application is somewhere out of the Spark cluster. Briefly my goal is to send requests and their accompanying data from web application via something such as POST to long running java program. then it receives the request and runs the corresponding spark driver (spark app) and returns the results for example in JSON format.

Is there any solution to develop this use case?
Is Livy a good choise? If your answer is positive what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at The Spark JobServer. I think it has the ability to shard RDD's between jobs which can be a huge performance boost.

https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver